# Add "Kubuntu Backports" PPA or "Kubuntu Updates" PPA? Or both?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, ppa, plasma, backport

https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports

https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

The first PPA is called "Kubuntu Backports" and the second PPA is called "Kubuntu Updates".

Which one of those two PPAs should I add to Kubuntu/Ubuntu in order to get the best and the most up to date KDE Plasma?  Or should I add both PPAs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest installing **only** the `kubuntu-backports` ppa when it becomes available for 18.04.

> Backports of new versions of KDE Platform, Plasma and Applications as well as major KDE apps for Kubuntu

from https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports

Also, you could monitor https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forumdisplay.php/30-Kubuntu-Announcements where Kubuntu devs will announce the kubuntu-backports releases.

You could also monitor [The kubuntu-devel Archives](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kubuntu-devel/) and, in particular https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kubuntu-devel/2018-May/011659.html as to what exactly will be provided via the kubuntu-backports ppa in 18.04.